# web based map from custom set of tiles

Tags: dictionary, tiles

I have set of pictures with scans of some paper map.
I want to create web based (google map like) zoomable & dragable map. 
Overall picture size is >10,000x10,000 so loading one dig picture is not a good idea. 
Ideally need something like 
http://www.afraidyet.net/forums/misc.php?do=page&template=Darkfall_Map 
welcomed feature - ability for user to leave his/her custom marks on the map (ideally sotred in local browser storage).

Foregt to mention it must be free for non commercial use :-)